# Google Apps Script custom style menu

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my first attempt at Google Apps scripting. I would like to add a simple menu with some custom styles for documents. Given the script [I found here](http://pastebin.com/4pNBJ9pC), i've [tried to implement it](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GStDXA0XNoayIG0mDEeRnZvU1d6FTuHsdtakbb03zx8/edit?usp=sharing). Can't seem to get it working though. I keep getting "Cannot find method..." errors

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you've made a few small errors that are understandable and easy to fix.

When declaring fontFamily in line 2, you passed it a string instead of a FontFamily object.

So change

```
var fontFamily = "ARIAL",
```

to

```
var fontFamily = DocumentApp.FontFamily.ARIAL,
```

And after that while you were correct to pass the colors as strings, they should be listed in hexadecimal values rather than words.

So on line 6, change

```
backgroundColor: "green",
```

to

```
backgroundColor: "#00FF00",
```

And on line 11 change

```
backgroundColor: "red",
```

to

```
backgroundColor: "#FF0000",
```

After that the menu should function as intended.

Comment: Side-note: While they weren't used in the code so wouldn't create any errors, based on the intended meaning of the variables it would probably be safer to change the `color: "white"` parts to `color: "#FFFFFF"` as well.